# Data relationship - looking for solutions

Tags: php, excel

I have a problem I need to solve and I'm sure there is a way of doing this, I'm just not exactly sure "what to search for" and how to find it.

I was thinking of doing this either in Excel or I could maybe try to make a PHP script to do it.

So basically, I have a set of substances. Each pair of substances is either compatible or incompatible with another one. So what I have is a table with rows and columns where there is either 0 or 1, i.e. compatible/incompatible.

Now what I want to do is try to find groups of substances, where all substances in that group are compatible with each other. And the goal is to find as large group as possible, or ideally, find the largest, second largest etc. and sort them from largest to smallest (given there could be some limitation for the minimum number of elements in that group).

I hope it makes sense, the problem is that I'm not sure how to solve it, but I think this is something that should be relatively commonly done and so I doubt the only way is writing a script/macro from scratch that would use brute force to do this. This would also probably not be very efficient as I have a table with over 30 elements.

So just to make it more clear, for example here is a simplified table of what my data looks like:

```
Substance              A   B  C  D
    A                  0   1  1  1
    B                  1   0  0  1
    C                  1   0  0  0
    D                  1   0  0  0
```

Comment: This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: Something is wrong....the table shows that **B** is compatible with **D**, but **D** is only compatible with **A** ???

Comment: Hi, sorry about the example, I just made that up for illustration purposes

Basically I need to create groups of substances, where all substances in that particular group are compatible with each other. And my goal is to create groups with as many elements as possible - ideally have them sorted from largest to smallest (given some minimum number of elements in that group).

Comment: some helpful search terms: clique problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem), adjacency matrix (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix)

Answer (score 1):

If you use only php without database you can use [uasort](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.uasort.php) to sort by sum all elements of related array.

```
<?php
$substances = [
    'A' => [
        'A' => 0,
        'B' => 1,
        'C' => 1,
        'D' => 0,
    ],
    'B' => [
        'A' => 1,
        'B' => 0,
        'C' => 1,
        'D' => 1,
    ],
    'C' => [
        'A' => 0,
        'B' => 1,
        'C' => 0,
        'D' => 0,
    ]
];
uasort ($substances, function ($a, $b) {
    $a = array_sum($a);
    $b = array_sum($b);
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a > $b) ? -1 : 1;
});
var_export($substances);
```